# How do I loop this login in Python?

Tags: python, function, loops, csv, authentication

How can I loop my login so that whenever someone signs in with the wrong username and password the program will ask the username and password again until it's correct.

```
def login():
    global Account
    UserName_File = 'users.csv'
    Separation = ','

    print('Welcome to the eHealth program, please sign in')
    UserName = input('Fill in your username: ')
    Password = input('Fill in your password: ')
    File = open(UserName_File, 'r')

    Signedin = False
    while Signedin != True:
        Account = File.readline()
        Account = Account.split(Separation)
        Account[-1] = Account[-1].strip('\n')
        print(Account)
        if Account[0] == '': #If the .csv file is empty or when the username and password are wrong 
            print('Failed to sign in, please try again')
            File.close()
            return
        else:
            UserName_File = Account[0]
            Password_File = Account[1]
            User = Account[2] #Doctor or patient
            if UserName_File == UserName and Password_File == Password and User == 'patient':
                Signedin = True
                print('Succesfully logged in, welcome patient')
                File.close()
                return
                #start to run patient functions
            elif UserName_File == UserName and Password_File == Password and User == 'doctor':
                Signedin = True
                print('Succesfully logged in, welcome doctor')
                File.close()
                return
                #start to run doctor functions

Account = ''
login()
print(Account)
```

the users.csv contains

```
username,password,function
patient,patient1,patient
doctor,doctor1,doctor
etc...
```

Comment: I hope this is a school assignment or some other form of toy program. Storing plaintext passwords in a CSV file is _exceptionally_ insecure.

Answer (score 0):

To get your current code to work, simply move the `input` section in to the while loop and remove the `return` calls. Fixed code:

```
def login():
    global Account
    UserName_File = 'users.csv'
    Separation = ','

    print('Welcome to the eHealth program, please sign in')

    Signedin = False

    while Signedin != True:

        UserName = input('Fill in your username: ')
        Password = input('Fill in your password: ')
        File = open(UserName_File, 'r')
        Account = File.readline()
        Account = Account.split(Separation)
        Account[-1] = Account[-1].strip('\n')
        print(Account)
        if Account[0] == '': #If the .csv file is empty or when the username and password are wrong 
            print('Failed to sign in, please try again')
            File.close()
        else:
            UserName_File = Account[0]
            Password_File = Account[1]
            User = Account[2] #Doctor or patient
            if UserName_File == UserName and Password_File == Password and User == 'patient':
                Signedin = True
                print('Succesfully logged in, welcome patient')
                File.close()
                #start to run patient functions
            elif UserName_File == UserName and Password_File == Password and User == 'doctor':
                Signedin = True
                print('Succesfully logged in, welcome doctor')
                File.close()
                #start to run doctor functions


Account = ''
login()
print(Account)
```

`return` will always exit the *function* it is being executed in, not the loop.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will keep looping the 'Failed to sign in, please try again' error.

Comment: @DamienBrils I made a lot of silly mistakes there, sorry. I'm working on a proper answer now.

Comment: @DamienBrils I think this should work now. Sorry for my previous awful answer.